# In OpenXML, how to ensure that the value of a cell overflows?

Tags: javascript, overflow, openxml

What is the attribute to ensure that the value of a cell overflows? Where do I need to set it? Is there a setting such as for 
''

I'm generating an OpenXML file in Javascript, not C# or VB, hence I do not have the methods available.

Microsoft documentation would refer to C# and VB methods only: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.aspx.

Comment: I am not sure if you can let the content of a cell overflow if the next cell contains some value, else by default it should overflow. What you can do it Wrap the text in the cell by adding a style `<alignment wrapText="1"/>` and referencing it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input, FortyTwo.

I have just figured out the solution: There is no setting. Just make sure that you do not have any  tags in the adjacent fields you want to have overflown.

JavaScript code:

```
        xmlFile += '        <Row>'; // Row 1
        xmlFile += '            <Cell ss:StyleID="default"><Data ss:Type="String"> Book Title </Data></Cell>';
        xmlFile += '            <Cell></Cell>'; // This cell will be overflown, first by the text to the left and then the text to the right
        xmlFile += '            <Cell ss:StyleID="right"><Data ss:Type="String"> This is a test on overflow </Data></Cell>';
        xmlFile += '        </Row>';

        xmlFile += '        <Row>'; // Row 1
        xmlFile += '            <Cell ss:StyleID="default"><Data ss:Type="String"> Book Title </Data></Cell>';
        xmlFile += '            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>'; // The data tags prevent overflow in this case
        xmlFile += '            <Cell ss:StyleID="right"><Data ss:Type="String"> This is a test on overflow </Data></Cell>';
        xmlFile += '        </Row>';
```

I hope this will help others working with OpenXML in JavaScript